# How do I translate swift NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints to objective c?

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, xib, nslayoutconstraint

I have successfully made a project in swift where I press buttons in my `viewController` to load other `viewControllers` or `xib` files into a container. Just to give you an idea:

[image]

It works great, but I'm having a difficult time translating it to `objective-c` which is where the code is actually needed. This is what the `swift` code looks like when pressing a button:

```
let sub3 = UINib(nibName: "thirdXib", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options: nil)[0] as! UIView

containerOutlet.addSubview(sub3)

NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    sub3.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerOutlet.leadingAnchor),
    sub3.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerOutlet.trailingAnchor),
    sub3.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerOutlet.topAnchor),
    sub3.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerOutlet.bottomAnchor)
        ])
```

Now, I would like all that code to be in `objective-c` instead. In `objective-c` I have done the first part, which I assume is correct:

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil];

[containerOutlet addSubview:((UIView*)nib)];
```

But I'm having problem with the last part, `NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints`

```
[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
        [nib.lead],
        [nib.centerXAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:self.view.centerXAnchor],
        ]
 ];
```

The compiler says that `property lead not found on object of type UIBib` and same on the code just below. I have tried a variation of these, but don't get it right. How do I set trailing, leading, bottom and top constraints on my xib? Do I need to add `#import SecondView.xib" in the`.h` file? by the way?

Comment: `sub3` is a `UIView`, `nib` is a `UINib*`. Try `UIView *sub3 = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil][0]`.

Comment: @Willeke I cast `nib` to `UIView` like this: `(UIView*)nib)` but it didn't seem to make a difference (changed original post as well).

Comment: `nib` is still a `UINib*`. Get view `UIView *sub3` from `[nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil][0]`.

Comment: @Willeke *sub3 is in a completely different project. I don't have access to it. Doesn't it work to typecast the way I did? Not sure I understand how to make it a `UIView` otherwise.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try

```
UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil]; 
UIView *sub3 = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil][0]; 
[containerOutlet addSubview:sub3];


[NSLayoutConstraint activateConstraints:@[
   [sub3.leadingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:scontainerOutlet.leadingAnchor],
   [sub3.trailingAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:containerOutlet.trailingAnchor],
   [sub3.topAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:containerOutlet.topAnchor],
   [sub3.bottomAnchor constraintEqualToAnchor:containerOutlet.bottomAnchor]
]];
```

Comment: Sorry, I might be a bit unclear. I'm not using `sub3` that's the `swift` code. In `objective-c` the `xib` reference is called `nib`. Would it possible to update the answer? Or am I misunderstanding your code?

Comment: Skipp everything with `*sub3` that's from a different project.

Comment: nib which is of type `UINib` can't be used with constraints , you need to get the view inside it , `sub3` is variable name not type it could be anything

Comment: OK, then I misunderstood. Thanks, I'll look into it and get back to you! :)

Comment: What is `SecondView`? The class associated with the `xib` view? The file owner? When I write it above, it's the file name, as in `SecondView.xib`.

Comment: The file owner is called `SecondViewController` is that what I should use in your case?

Comment: yes class name of the nib you can make it `UIView` also

Comment: Alright! Setting `*sub3` as `UIView` worked like a charm. I got access to all the constraint properties. Thanks a bunch for taking the time helping me out! :)

Comment: This answer worked *almost perfectly for me. I did have to add sub3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false; before calling activateConstraints to completely fix the issue.